# Не могу зайти на виртуальный хост (Elementary OS)

Tags: ubuntu, apache, elementary-os

все сделал по [инструкции](http://dev-mark.blogspot.com/2011/01/kohana-3-ubuntu.html) (не знаю можно ли постороннее ссылки выкладывать, так что простите на перед).

после выполнения команды вот что написало a2ensite

```
sg_ua@maxim-Aspire-5733Z:~$ sudo a2ensite kohana.ubuntu
```

> Enabling site kohana.ubuntu. To activate the new configuration, you
>   need to run:   service apache2 reload

перезагрузил апачи...но у браузере долго соединяется, в итого ошибка

> Эта страница не доступна

вот мой файл kohana.ubuntu.config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin    webmaster@ubuntu
 ServerName     kohana.ubuntu


 DocumentRoot /home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/webroot

 <Directory "/home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/webroot">
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes
      AllowOverride All
      Order Allow,Deny
      Allow From All
 </Directory>

 ErrorLog     /home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/logs/access.log combined
```

Answer (score 1):

Конфигурация virtualhost изменилась.

Было в 2.2:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Стало в 2.4:

```
Require all granted
```

Comment: все ровно не грузиться

Comment: В /etc/hosts что прописали? Как в инструкции? `10.0.0.4     kohana.ubuntu` правильно вот так: `127.0.0.1     kohana.ubuntu`

Comment: изменил на `127.0.0.1`, уже загружается, только не то что нужно, оно подгружает со стандартной папки, а не с `/home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/webroot`

Comment: Можно скриншот содержимого `/home/sg_ua/vhosts/kohana/webroot`?

Comment: `sg_ua@maxim-Aspire-5733Z:~/vhosts/kohana/webroot$   ls `результат:
`index.php`
там только файл php и его содержание `<?php phpinfo() ?>`

Comment: Так у тебя там фреймворка нет, скачай его отсюда https://github.com/kohana/kohana/releases/download/v3.3.3.1/kohana-3.3.3.1.zip и распакуй в папку webroot

Comment: просто в инструкции автор запускает без фреймворка

Comment: Да, должна быть страница с информацией о PHP, а у тебя что?

Comment: *Конфигурация virtualhost изменилась* — старые опции пока действуют (хотя и *deprecated*) при наличии модуля [mod_access_compat](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html)

Comment: у меня показывает что находиться в стандартной папке /var/www/html

Comment: вот мой [скрин хост файла](http://storage3.static.itmages.com/i/15/0708/h_1436367791_7316940_d93e94cd22.png)